# How can I map dates in python using lambdas? I am trying to do this to print Excel sheet in Odoo

Tags: lambda, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to map keys for Excel sheet using lambdas. But I can't map properly. Please help

```
def _get_lines(self,cr,uid,ids,val, context=None):
    dict_dat = val
    od_start = dict_dat['od_start'][0]
    qry= ''
    x = 'hr_payslip.date_from = '+ date(od_start)
    print x
    qry = x
    qry_data = []
    qry = self.make_qry(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
    keys = self.get_keys()
    cr.execute(qry)
    qry_data = cr.fetchall()
    der_data = map(lambda x:dict(zip(keys,x)),qry_data)
    print der_data
    return der_data
```

Comment: It helps if you can be more specific about your problem.

Comment: @ThomasSmyth : In this line """x = 'hr_payslip.date_from = '+ date(od_start)""" 
Here I want to fetch od_start ,which is a date field...
How can I do this..?

Comment: Solved the issue.

Comment: If it is solved please consider writing that as an answer and accepting it to help others who may view this question in the future.

Comment: Ok @ThomasSmyth. 
I am new here.

Comment: `x = 'hr_payslip.date_from = '+ str(val.get('od_start'))`
Solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = 'hr_payslip.date_from = '+ str(val.get('od_start'))
```

Solved the problem